# Excel VBA: Specify file name and file location to save

Tags: vba

I am trying to use Excel VBA to automatically save down a file. I need to save the file with a:

(1) Dynamic name by date: XYZ & today's date (for example "XYZ 20180825")

(2) Static location: let's say that I need to save the file in the directory "C:\Program Files"

I am wondering how I can reflect that in VBA.

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2268-excel-add-date-to-filename.html

Comment: Did you actually try solving this problem before you posted or do you expect someone else to do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a crashcourse, sorry for the language mix ...

Create and write file

```
Sub SchreibeDatei()
Dim strDateiname As String, strDateipfad As String

strDateiname = Date & Time & "test.txt"
strDateipfad = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strDateiname

' Datei erzeugen und/oder schreiben
Open strDateipfad For Output As #1
        Print #1, ""
        Print #1, ""
Close #1
End Sub
```

Append to existing file

```
Sub ErweitereDatei()
Dim strDateiname As String, strDateipfad As String

strDateiname = "test.txt"
strDateipfad = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strDateiname

Open strDateipfad For Append As #1
        Print #1, ""
Close #1
End Sub
```

Read file

```
Sub LeseDatei()
Dim strDateiname As String, strDateipfad As String
Dim strZeile As String, strInhalt As String

strDateiname = "test.txt"
strDateipfad = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strDateiname

' Datei zeilenweise lesen
Open strDateipfad For Input As #1
While Not EOF(1)                                ' EOF = EndOfFile
    Line Input #1, strZeile
    strInhalt = strInhalt + strZeile & Chr(10)
Wend
Close #1

MsgBox strInhalt
End Sub
```

Delete file

```
Sub LoescheDatei()
Dim strDateiname As String, strDateipfad As String

strDateiname = "test.txt"
strDateipfad = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strDateiname

Kill(strDateipfad)
End Sub
```

Changing names, location and including datetime you will find!

Comment: I think your answer is a bit overkill - they don’t need to write into or out of the file, they just want the file name to include a chunk of the current date